# display volume view/ MPVolumeView iphone-sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

I have developed a video player application and I am also changing the volume of music player from my application. So I want to display default volume change view/indicator when volume is change from my application. So please suggest.

I am using below code for change the volume:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
```

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: want to display volume change view when volume changed using application.

Comment: if you do not add any new view for MPVolumeView, the standard one will be placed

Comment: No its not placed automatically.

Comment: is the volume changing?

Comment: yes in the volume changing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62977/discussion-between-mitesh-khatri-and-julian-krol).